# Pokémon Selection Strategy for Emerald

Tags: pokemon-series

I've gotten about midway into Pokémon Emerald -- completed the third badge (electric badge), and starting to get quite an assortment of Pokémon.

The problem is, I can't figure out which ones to keep and raise experience for, and which ones to leave rotting in the PC. My old strategy used to be "pick the most interesting-looking ones and always power up the weakest" -- this lead to some surprising strengths (like the mushroom one with Mega Drain).

What strategy should I use? How do I know which Pokémon to select and train, and when I capture new ones, how do I decide to add them to my party (and drop a different one) or leave them in the box?

Also, I have the "Exp Share" item, so I can easily power up weak Pokémon in a low-risk fashion. w00t!

Comment: @Ullallulloo - Emerald (or at least, 3rd gen) is significant, because it was the last game before they changed the combat mechanics (the Physical / special split). If you remove the "Emerald" descriptor, you change the nature of the question entirely.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Yeah, I know, but that's a very minor influence in selecting your party.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - I was thinking in terms of specific pokémon suggestions: For instance, Absol as a Dark coverage is ill suited for the role in 3rd gen due to Dark being special and Absol having much better Attack, but is much better off in 4th gen, where Bite et al get to use Attack instead. If answers refrain from specific pokémon suggestions, it is perhaps, more minor.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Oh, I see what you mean. That's a good point. It would be a lot harder and rather subjective to provide lists of good and bad Pokémon though.

Comment: I'm not looking for a good and bad list. I'm looking for a set of metrics by which I can analyze pokemon and decide which ones to keep and which to throw out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it comes down to personal preference, really. Aside from the very high level legendaries you can catch, there's no magic group of pokemon that will get you through the game with minimal effort. There are two good guidelines though.

1) A good balance of types

2) Leveling, leveling, leveling.

Getting a balance of types is pretty easy. You just want to get 6 pokemon, such that you won't end up in a situation where one poke type counters half your team. For example, my old gold team was

Kadabra (Psychic)
Typhlosion (Fire)
Suicune (Water)
Graveler (Rock/Ground)
Weepinbell (Grass)
and one more I can't remember right now. (Oh well, you get the point.)

The other thing you need to do is level. Not just what you'd get from fighting every trainer, and leveling a team of 6 pokemon from that, I mean running around in the grass for hours to level. A good baseline would be lvl 10 for the first gym, and another 5 levels for every gym leader after that. If you do that, your party should be about on par with most of the trainers you come across.

Sadly, that won't be enough for the elite 4. IIRC, some of the champion's pokemon are in the 60's level wise, and although you can abuse type advantage, that won't make up for a 15 level difference. You have two choices at this point.

1) Spend more hours leveling up until you can beat them.
2) Catch Rayquaza, and curb stomp them with a level 70 legendary.

I picked the latter. MUCH faster. ;)

One last thing, make sure you evolve your pokemon, as it improves their stats drastically. Additionally, trained pokemon are actually a good deal more powerful than wild pokemon, even if the wild one is a few levels higher. The reason for this is somewhat convulted, but basically as you level up your pokemon manually, their stats will improve based on the pokemon they fought, in addition to the normal level up bonus. However, you don't need to worry about the mechanics behind it (unless you plan to play competitively, in which case you'd need more help then I could give you.)

Hope all of this helps.

Comment: For reference, I managed to beat the elite four in Pearl with pokemon ~10 levels below the champion, but *only* because I had a Skarmory that was tanking non-fire attakcs, giving me a chance to use items. Level *matters* and it is hard to keep up with the gym leader's pokemon levels if you don't spend extra time in the grass.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic strategy is to try to get a wide variety of types and [physical](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Physical_move)/[special](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Special_move) Pokémon with high [base stats](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Base_stats). ([List of Pokémon by base stats](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_stats)) A variety of types is important so you can counter your foes' types, and a variety of physical and special is kind of important so you can counter your foes' defenses. (Sometimes, but this isn't actually that important, unless you're a really serious player with a list of Pokémon's base stats at hand to know which stat's weaker, and since physical and special are dependent on type in Gen III it's even less so.) High base stats are important because that's basically what determines how strong your Pokémon is.

For example, a bad party would be:

- Sceptile
- Beautifly
- Dustox
- Shiftry
- Masquerain
- Sunflora

A better party would be:

- Sceptile
- Metagross
- Arcanine
- Gyarados
- Jolteon
- Shuckle

You probably don't, however, just want to switch your Pokémon willy-nilly, since trained Pokemon are stronger than Pokemon raised in the wild due to [EVs](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values). ([List of Pokémon by effort value yield](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_effort_value_yield))

If you're just playing rather casually though, pretty much any Pokémon will do and just sticking with one party of Pokémon that you like will be the best strategy, and, tbh, if you're looking to build the perfect, strongest party, you'd finish the plot first and then hatch a new party out from eggs that are specially bred for the perfect moves & IVs and then train them for perfect EVs. You wouldn't try to play through with them originally since you'd have to wait for quite a while in the game to find the strongest Pokémon, and then you wouldn't use those for playing through more of the story, since you can't know what EVs the Pokémon that trainers send out first will give. (Unless you use the "Emerald Berries" that lower EVs, I guess.)

Comment: I am indeed playing casually. Initially, picking randomly based on what looks interesting is great. But later on, my powerful pokemon get pwned quite badly, and I'm left holding a collection of weaker and useless secondary pokemon. Hence, my question.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you are playing the campaign, in which case there's only one thing to do: get a Pokemon that can learn as many HM moves as possible (e.g. Cut, Surf, Fly). These moves are usually pretty mediocre at best - Surf is an exception - so you just farm it out to a so-called "[HM slave](https://levelskip.com/rpgs/best-hm-slaves-in-Pokemon)". For the rest of your Pokemon you can just train whatever blows your hair. This works because the NPC trainers aren't very powerful, and there's nothing you can't beat just by getting a higher-level Pokemon. To illustrate, I once beat Misty (the Water gym leader in Pokemon R/B/Y) with Charizard. Like yeah, her water attacks are super-effective, but when her Pokemon are level 20 and my Charizard is level 36, there's no way I lose. Just about the only PvE thing where your comp matters is at the Battle Tower, but long win streaks at the Battle Tower require special tactics that is best left for another question.

Against other players, it's a completely different matter because you won't have a level advantage, and you need to build a real team. Broadly speaking there are two types of teams (this is *very* broadly speaking): offense and stall.

Offensive teams aim to kill the opponent before the opponent kills them. They will often have some plan that looks like this: "I'll use X to weaken my opponent's counter to Y. Once that's done, I'll bring in Y, set up, and kill my opponent's team." Their Pokemon won't be able to take many hits, if at all. If the opponent is faster with their plan, then offensive teams tend to die really quickly.

At the other end is stall. Here you have a lot of bulky Pokemon that can take hits and recover health. The basic gameplan is to absorb whatever your opponent can throw at you before winning with attrition damage (from entry hazards, Toxic, etc.). Well-built stall teams will rarely be 6-0'ed, because even if opponent gets in their stat-boosting move like Swords Dance, the stall team will be able to handle the +2 Pokemon.

A common way to build offensive teams is to figure out what Pokemon you want to sweep with. For example, say you choose Raikou. Then you figure out what Pokemon stops Raikou from sweeping. In this case special walls (e.g. Chansey) are complete halt to Raikou. Then you figure out how to stop that special wall. For example, you might play Dugtrio, which traps Chansey and finishes it off. With opponent's Raikou counter gone, you might be able to get a sweep off.

With stall teams, it's usually different. You look through the threat list of every Pokemon in the metagame, and figure out how you plan to stop them. For example say your opponent might have a Gyarados. [In R/S/E, this is a Water/Flying Pokemon that usually attacks on the physical side with Ground, Flying/Rock and possibly Normal moves. It usually has Dragon Dance.](https://www.smogon.com/dex/rs/pokemon/gyarados/) But as you can see from that article, Zapdos completely crushes Gyarados. It doesn't matter if Gyarados has already used Dragon Dance, because you beat it anyway. If your team has a Zapdos, then you don't need to worry about Gyarados. You work through the threat list one by one to make sure you can account for most threats your opponent might have.

Note offensive teams also have to take the threat list into account, because otherwise you are just too fragile. But offensive teams usually rely on offensive checks, not counters. Against Gyarados for example, the plan might be to hit it hard with whatever you already have in play, such that it no longer has the health to sweep.

Ultimately building a team is not easy, and players spend hours fine-tuning. If you're doing it from scratch, Smogon (linked above) is a great resource. Pick your favorite Pokemon, then look through their analysis page to choose good partners.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure that you have an Electric-type, a Fire-type, a Water-type, a Ground-type, a Flying-type, and maybe another good type like Psychic or Dark, doesn't matter which one. Or you could just get your favorite legendary, or another type that you like!